# twisted exception on periodic task

Tags: django, twisted

I have a django application running under twisted.
I have server.py with the following code: http://slexy.org/view/s21TBxGPut
When I run server.py with twisted I get the following exception: http://slexy.org/view/s2WqQDMvsh

The exception is caused by the last 2 lines in server.py. If I comment these lines, I have no exception. 
I have no idea how to debug such thing. 
Maybe someone has an idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot, Arshavski Alexander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TimerService` is constructed wrong:

```
ts2 = TimerService(3600, call_command("tamarin_pull_logs"))
```

This is the same as:

```
some_func = call_command("tamarin_pull_logs")
ts2 = TimerService(3600, some_func)
```

What does `call_command` return?  It's not part of your paste, but since your exception is:

```
exceptions.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I'm going to guess that it returns `None`.  And `None` is not callable, as the exception points out.

You set up the first `TimerService` correctly:

```
ts = TimerService(86400, check_all_notifications)
```

Notice that you're not calling `check_all_notifications` in that statement.  You're **passing** it to `TimerService`.  You need to do the same for your other service:

```
ts2 = TimerService(3600, call_command, "tamarin_pull_logs")
```

It just so happens that `TimerService` is constructed to support calling a function with some arguments, so it accepts both the callable and arbitrary extra arguments and passes those arguments on to the callable whenever it is time to call it.